Does the adjective "numerous" require plural subjects? Are there any other words with this property?
As a (nonnative) long-time English learner, I found that descriptive grammars often point out that verbs like surround, gather, disband, etc. require plural subjects:

(1a) The girl surrounded the house.
(1b) * The girls surrounded the house.

It is known that the notion of plurality at issue is semantic, not formal or morphological: the singular NP the army refers to a collective rather than an individual, but it is still OK in (2a) below. According to this line of argument, (2b) would presumably entail--though I'd like to hear your take on this one--that there are more than one pair of trousers enveloping the kitten, even if conceptually there is nothing wrong with the notion of a kitten being engulfed by the fabric of a single pair of trousers.

(2a) The army is surrounding the town.
(2b) Her trousers are surrounding the little kitten.

My question concerns the claim made by Krifka et al (1995) that some adjectives like numerous require plural subjects on purely formal grounds, regardless of their semantics. Consider (3).

(3a) *That army of soldiers is numerous
(3b) The soldiers in that army are numerous.

Although the phenomenon appears to be dialect-dependent, in that some people might consider (3a) natural, I was wondering if there are other adjectives that behave like numerous when found in predicative position (cf. the attributive use in their numerous family), besides the near-synonyms like copious, multitudinous, or innumerable.
What about disparate v. dissimilar? Only dissimilar allows for the structure X is dissimilar to Y besides X and Y are dissimilar. Would you agree e.g. with the judgements in (4)?

(4a) *The mixture of ingredients is disparate
(4b) The ingredients being mixed are disparate

disparate does seem to be in an entirely different semantic class than numerous, so there might be others like it. Perhaps someone who's more well-versed than me on English lexicology can point me toward other examples of this curious phenomenon.

While there is one overarching theme to this question, it seems to have several sub-questions. It might be best to "prune" unnecessary branches.

@AndyBonner The first question of the title is rhetorical--yes, it's a word that requires a formally plural subject according to most grammars. What I am interested in is whether there are other clear-cut examples.

Merriam-Webster – a wall surrounds the old city. Whatever  'rule' you find, there will be exceptions.

@WeatherVane Your examples exploit the stative sense of the verb, which is not restricted in the manner described in the post. You cannot say "A fence surrounded the house in two hours" (cf. "The cops surrounded the house in five minutes").

A wall surrounded the city within five years.

Is the question asking simply for "examples of this curious phenomenon"?

Google Books has plenty examples of "is numerous". "The species, we are told, is numerous in the mountains of Abyssinia and of Upper Egypt" Oliver Goldsmith (not the famous one), 1859. "... where the latter is numerous, the former rarely resides", Wilson's American Ornithology, 1840. "Wells. Though now mainly found in north-east Ulster, where it is numerous...". The Surnames of Ireland, 6th Edition, Edward MacLysaght, 1988. And specialised: "When you say of a propositional function that it is numerous, you will mean that there are several values of x that will satisfy it..." Bertrand Russell

Did you mean to put an asterisk next to (1a) instead of (1b)?

Also: I actually did initially read (2b) as describing the fabric of a single pair of trousers.

Another note: with "surround," the subject doesn't even need to be collective: "A wall surrounded the city."

Your assertion about what one ‘cannot’ say with surround seems so demonstrably untrue it’s silly. Where in the world did you find it? Charlotte Brontë wrote on page 243 of Jane Eyre vol. III. ix: “He surrounded me with his arm, almost as if he loved me.” Similar examples are readily obtainable from treasured volumes of English literature which we hold in highest regard, examples whose acceptability your putative ‘rule’ would appear to deny. Native speakers know a river can surround an isle; a frame, an aperture; an arm, a companion; an atmosphere, a planet. Perhaps you’ve misunderstood?

@Zoltan Just look for the head of the subject NP; this will determine the number of the verb. For example, singular "mixture" takes singular "is* and plural "ingredients" takes plural "are". Just basic elementary grammar.

Arguably, 'numerous' is always a quantifier (determiner).

To focus on the last part of your question: although I agree with your judgments about (4a) and (4b) in particular, there are certainly contexts in which disparate can readily be used predicatively with a singular predicand.
Take this paper on criminology:

Even though criminal behavior is disparate and complex, with different causal histories, general crime theories are still possible.

Or this sentence from a debate in the UK Parliament:

However, because, by its nature, its audience is disparate, the chances are that their views will not be expressed in the consultation.


Is calling the audience disparate the UK version of what corporate America now means by saying that the audience is diverse?

@tchrist In context, I think it means "geographically dispersed"--it's about the benefits of local over national radio.
